# convert days hours minutes seconds to iso 8601

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, safari

here is my script

```
var specialDate = "<?php echo trim(date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s',strtotime($time[1])));?>";
    var countDownDate = new Date(specialDate).getTime();
var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance =   countDownDate -  now;

var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

var countdown = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
```

the above code is working perfectly fine on all the browsers except for safari.
after googling I came to know I need to convert this to iso 8601 compliant to work for safari (currently it is showing nand nanh nanm nans error on safari browser iphone 6 )

I is the detail of of my phone
[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**
here is page source
[image]

Comment: It's not an error, it's a value ...

Comment: so is distance a timestamp or is it a countdown (in millisecond) ?

Comment: @Teemu this `var countdown` is my countdown timer working fine on all the browser. can you suggest its alternate if I need to modify it

Comment: Nothing wrong with code shown. Provide a [mcve] that reproduces issue and also the error thrown

Comment: @MuhammadAsifRaza Nope, I've no clue what is the value of `distance`. Or actually I have, ... PHP timestamp is based on seconds, not  on milliseconds as JS Date object.

Comment: I have added few more lines of code on top of my current scripts. that might help you in identifying the problem

Comment: Can't you change the serverside code returning all values separately?

Comment: Problem is the php date format probably. What format is `$time[1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the following:

```
var specialDate = "<?php echo trim(date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s',strtotime($time[1])));?>";
    var countDownDate = new Date(specialDate).getTime();
```

To:

```
// echo php timestamp
var specialDate = <?php echo strtotime($time[1]);?>;
// multiply by 1000 for equivalent of `Date.getTime()`
var countDownDate = specialDate * 1000;
```

Comment: In page source what do you see as value for `specialDate `?

Comment: I have edited the question and added screenshot of the function viewed in source

Comment: Ok that's a date string. Seems you didn't output `strtotime()` on it as I suggested

Comment: the following line of code show me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null error
`document.getElementById("buy_0").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";`
so I need to convert it to strtotime() as you suggested ?

Comment: Right....I was asking what the page source looks like when you used my answer. You already knew the original one doesn't work properly

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

here is the source after applying strtotime()

`var specialDate = strtotime("Y-m-d H:i:s",  11/30/2017 2:00 PM);`

Comment: even if I apply simple strtotime without any format I get the same syntaxt error

`var specialDate = strtotime(11/30/2017 2:00 PM);`

Comment: atlast solved the issue. bundle of thanks for guiding me